# How to count blank spaces in a string using for loop

Tags: java, string, for-loop, char, java.util.scanner

How would I code a for loop that prints the amount of spaces in a string that the user inputs? In my for loop, when I coded if (ch == "  "), the compiler says "incomparable types: char and java.lang.String." When I code (ch == ' '), it says "unclosed character literal". Thank you in advance

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Count{

public static void main (String[] args){

  Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
  String phrase;    // a string of characters
  int countBlank;   // the number of blanks (spaces) in the phrase 
  int length;       // the length of the phrase
  int i = 0;
  char ch;          // an individual character in the string    
  // Print a program header
  System.out.println ();
  System.out.println ("Character Counter");
  System.out.println ();




  // Read in a string and find its length
  System.out.print ("Enter a sentence or phrase: ");
  phrase = scan.nextLine(); // read input Scanner 
  // Find the length of the phrase 

  // Initialize counts
  countBlank = 0;

  // a for loop to go through the string character by character
  // and count the blank spaces
  for (i = 0; ch < length; i++){
  ch = phrase.charAt(i);
  if (ch == '  ')
  countBlank++;
  }

  // Print the results
  System.out.println ();
  System.out.println ("Number of blank spaces: " + countBlank);
  System.out.println ();
    }
}
```

Comment: Double quotes signify a string literal thus the error reporting you can't compare a char to a string. Use single quotes for char literals.

Comment: As Andrew said, so try this `ch == '  '` or you can cast(Not true casting, but I mean convert into a String) `ch+"".equal(" ")`; I recommend the first one. I edited my comment because you can't compare two strings that way.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I have actually tried using single quotes but the compiler says "unclosed character literal". I was gonna respond earlier but lost time. How do I close the character literal? Thanks for your help! I will change the double quotes to single quotes in my post to attempt to make it not a duplicate question.